# Two Finger Click Event using Windows 7 Multi-Touch

Tags: wpf, windows-7, multi-touch

We would like 2 code samples (C# would be great) of Windows 7 multitouch functionality using .NET 3.5 sp1 and the ManipulationProcessor:

1. A two finger click sample – An event should be raised when a user “clicks” on a UIElement such as a Rectangle using 2 fingers simultaneously (Close together).  The click event should be fired when the “down” events occur, not when “up” events occur.
2. A two finger drag sample – A delta event should be fired when a user places two fingers next to each other and drags them up or down the screen.  Data needed is “delta amount” – the how far the fingers have dragged since the last Delta event as well as “delta direction” to indicate whether the user had dragged their fingers up or down the screen.  This is similar to the Y Translation delta data that’s already present in ManipulationProcessor.ManipulationDelta, but should only be triggered when 2 fingers are present and next to each other throughout the gesture.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a nice demo](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/PC03/) on doing multitouch applications. Littered with code samples.